# Git - Help me understand and improve my two-man workflow

Tags: git, workflow

A teammate and I (both new to git) are working on a new project.  This project is still in the very early stages of development, so changes are not at a point where they can be broken into well-isolated features.

This is our current workflow.  (I know it's probably wrong)...

- `git commit`
- `git pull origin`
- `git push origin`

I'm having trouble understanding the results in the following scenario...

- I commited a small change locally
- My teammate made a series of commits and pushed to origin
- I finished what I was working on, commited again
- I pulled in his changes, and pushed back to origin

Afterwards, I expected the diff to show my changes, since that's what's new to origin.  Instead, I see my teammates changes added to my code.  In addition, my teammate received errors when trying to pull (did not record them, unfortunately), and had to clone to get things working right again.

To make things look like I expected in the first place, I (after searching around stackoverflow)...

- `git reset --hard`
- `git checkout <teammates last commit>`
- `git merge <my last commit>`
- `git push`

First, I'd like to understand what happened.  Second, I'd like to know a better approach going forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without more information on what the errors were, it's hard to say why they occurred.  It may be that binary files were modified (this often causes Git errors), but it could be lots of other things, too.

It sounds to me like Git is working correctly:  The last change you did was to pull in your teammate's changes, and that's reflected in the most recent git diff.  You would normally want to pull *before* doing the commit, to make sure that you're working with an up to date version of the repository.  Also, the `diff` command works on the commit history; when you pushed to the origin is irrelevant.

In the future, you may want to look into working with branches.  If you each have your own branch, you can use `git rebase` to pull in any changes that have been made to the master branch before committing your modifications.  Working with local branches makes collaborating easier, because you don't have to worry about committing changes that aren't yet ready for prime time to the master branch.  A nice tutorial on branching can be found at: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging.  I've found it very useful in the past.

Answer (score 0):

a git pull will merge all changes from the remote into your local repo. since your teammate pushed new changes when you did a pull it merged them into your local repo. A pull does a fetch and a merge behind the scenes. Without knowing the errors your teammate got its hard to determine what went wron